# Newbie variable passing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd really appreciate if you could give me a quick hand with this little problem I'm having. So far in programming, I've done some C, but I'm confused as to how to pass variables through functions in Python.

I'm sure that this question has been asked many times, but I have no idea what to search for.

My code is:

```
x=0
def getinput(x):
    x = input('Enter x: ')
def addtwo(x):
    x = x + 2
def printans(x):
    print 'x is', + x

getinput(x)
addtwo(x)
printans(x)
```

`printans` always ends up printing `0`. I'm sure that it's because the variables inside of the functions are local, but I don't know how to fix that in python.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Downvoter: would you like to provide a reason? This is a well written question and addresses something that new python programmers are not familiar with.

Comment: I think some people feel its appropriate to downvote questions that they feel are too basic for their own liking. As if its wrong for a beginner to ask a legitimate beginners question. Not everyone starting out knows all the right terms to search for the right answer. I support that this is a well written question and not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: It seems like I've seen a sudden proliferation of this specific sort of question (failing to understand how parameter passing and return values work), both here and elsewhere on the Internet. I wonder if someone just put out a bad tutorial?

Comment: BTW, OP, the problem you're experiencing *would be exactly the same in C*.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that *you are not returning the values* you get/compute inside your functions.

I won't give you *all* of the code, but if you understand this example, you'll be able to make the necessary adjustments to the rest of your own code as needed as part of learning to program with Python.

```
def addtwo(x):
    x = x + 2 # compute your result
    return x  # return the result to caller


result = addtwo(5) # save the returned value
print result       # print it out
```

yields

```
7
```

You want to do something similar to `getinput()` function too since it gets a value that you want to use in your program. This is in contrast to `printans()` which simply takes information to print, but doesn't compute anything that needs to be returned to you.

Note that as you get more comfortable with this, you can shorten your code/expression, so for the example above, your whole function could consist of

```
 def addtwo(x):
    return x + 2
```

but until then there's nothing wrong with doing things step-by-step explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue regarding global and local scope. While you functions can access `x` as a global scope value, when you reassign the variable, you are shadowing the global, but then you don't return the value:

```
# return local 
def getinput(x):
    x = input('Enter x: ')
    return x

# affect global 
def getinput(x):
    global x
    x = input('Enter x: ')
```

Using a local variable and returning a value is usually preferable to modifying globals unless you have a completely justifiable situation for it.

*A note about mutable and immutable types*

There is a second case to this situation, and that is regarding the type of object which you are affecting. `int` and `string`, for instance, are immutable. You cannot change their value without creating a new object as a result. A `list` or `dict` are examples of mutable types. You can add and remove from them, changing their value.

Consider a mutable type `list`

```
aList = []
def func():
    aList.append(1)

print aList # prints []
func()
print aList # prints [1]
```

This will append to the global list just fine without even specifying a global keyword, because the list itself is still the same list object. But if you were to overwrite that list with a new list, without the global, it will not take effect globally:

```
aList = []
def func():
    aList = [1]
```

In a nutshell, mutable types don't need the global keyword if you are just going to modify the contents of the object, but not assign a new object.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I was looking for one way to solve my problem, and I got two!

Comment: There are two ways, but the "return local" one is almost always the better one.  Definitely use that one.

Comment: It's more of a mutable/immutable thing. If you modified a mutable type (say a `list`) inside a function, the changes persist in the global scope. This is not true for immutable types like `int`s

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Its can be both actually. `x` could be a list and assigning it a new list will shadow the global

Comment: @jdi: This is true (+1). I was thinking of modifying in-place. I should have made that clearer

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Thanks. I actually just updated with info about that. Good call

Answer (score 2):

The variables in the functions are local, as you have said.  The way to fix it is to return values from your functions:

```
def getinput():
    return input('Enter x: ')

def addtwo(x):
    return x + 2

def printans(x):
    print 'x is', + x

x = getinput()
x = addtwo(x)
printans(x)
```

To put it in C terms, when dealing with numbers, it works the same as if everything is pass by value.